# Where is the scientific evidence to support the assertion that nothing can travel faster than light in vacuum?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, faster-than-light

It is true that so far, nothing has ever been observed to travel faster than light in vacuum. However, just because nothing so far has yet to travel faster than light does not mean that nothing in the universe can travel faster than light.

Are there solid evidence supported by experiments to support the assertion that nothing travels faster than light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Particles in particle accelerators are given immense amounts of energy, and none so far have surpassed the speed of light. According to Wikipedia (and the math seems to check out), protons in the LHC are traveling at about 99.999999% of the speed of light. Remember that the point of the accelerator is to get the particles to go as fast as possible; every new design for the past 80 years or so has only manged to add more 9's to that number. And if a particle had gone over the speed of light, we would surely know, if only because of the incredible precision with which these experiments are done. Just to drive the point home, a few years ago the OPERA team, due to some experimental error, though they had detected neutrinos moving faster than the speed of light by a factor of 1 in 40000.

No amount evidence is equal to proof, but this is surely as close as it gets.

Comment: I have to say that the validation comes not just from the failure to break the nominal limit but also from the tight mathematical agreement between the prediction of the theory and the perfomance on the ground. In essence the statement that "nothing can go faster than the speed of light in vacuum" is a theoretical one, but the theory is depends on is well validated.

Comment: @dmckee: I thought of doing that, but I figured I should keep it simple and to the point. I thought OP would not be entirely convinced by more theoretical arguments.